# How to get HTML from URL that returns "junk" data?

Tags: python, html

I want to get the html source code of a given url. I had tried using this

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://mp3.zing.vn' # write the url here

usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = usock.read()
usock.close()

print data
```

But the returned data is not in HTML format for some pages. I tried with another link like `http://phuctrancs.info` and it works (as this page is plain html based). I have also tried using `BeautifulSoup` library but it didn't work also. Any suggestion?

Comment: I tried the script you put up, and it works. Can you be specific as to which pages are not in HTML format?

Comment: I have tried with the `url = 'http://mp3.zing.vn'` and the return data is likely 
encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the HTML you expect, but it's *compressed*.  I tried this URL by hand and got back a binary mess with this in the headers:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

I saved the response body to a file and was able to `gunzip` it on the command line.  You should also be able to decompress it in your program with the functions in the standard library's [`zlib` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html).

**Update** for anyone having trouble with [`zlib.decompress`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompress)...

The compressed data you will get (or at least that *I* got in Python 2.6) apparently has a "gzip header and trailer" like you'd expect in `*.gz` files, while `zlib.decompress` expects a "zlib wrapper"... probably.  I kept getting an unhelpful `zlib.error` exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fixme.py", line 32, in <module>
    text = zlib.decompress(data)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

The solution is *entirely undocumented* in the Python standard library, but can be found in [Greg Hewgill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112732/zip-encrypted-gziped-files-with-python/10112842#10112842) to a question about `gzip` streams:  You have to **feed `zlib.decompress` a `wbits` argument**, created by adding a magic number to an undocumented module-level constant  <*grumble*, *mutter*...>:

```
text = zlib.decompress(data, 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

If you feel this isn't obfuscated enough, note that a `32` here would be every bit as magical as the `16`.

The only hint of this is buried in the [*original* zlib's manual](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html), under the `deflateInit2` function:

> `windowBits` can also be greater than 15 for optional *gzip* decoding.  Add 16 to `windowBits` to write a simple *gzip* header and trailer around the compressed data instead of a *zlib* wrapper.

...and the `inflateInit2` function:

> **`windowBits` can also be greater than 15** for optional *gzip* decoding. Add 32 to `windowBits` to enable *zlib* and *gzip* decoding with automatic header detection, or **add 16 to decode only the *gzip* format** [...]

Note that the [`zlib.decompress` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompress) explicitly tell you that you *can't* do this:

> The default value is therefore **the highest value, 15**.

But this is... the opposite of true.

<*fume*, *curse*, *rant*...>

Answer (score 1):

have you look into the response code, urllib2 may need you to handle the response such as 301 redirect and so on.
you should print the response code like:

```
data = usock.read()
if usock.getcode() != 200:
    print "something unexpected"
```

updated:
 if the response contains None-localized or none-readable text, then you might need to specify the request character set in the request header.

```
import cookielib
cookie = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie))
opener.addheaders = [("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8")]
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

PS: untested.

Comment: I think you haven't got my problem yet. The given page is available to access (the `getcode()` returns 200). But the data is in human-unreadable text

Comment: If the response contains none-localized text, then you might add the charset to the request header.

Comment: this is not human-unreadable text, the reason it is unreadable to you is the charset is special

Comment: I have tried adding the charset in the header but nothing changes. The same problem. I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

use beautiful soup from python

```
import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.google.com'
r=request.get(url)
b=BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

b will contain all the html tags and also provides you iteractor to traverse elements/tags. To know more link is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/4.3.2